# Django Rest Framework test fails: Expected view to be called with a URL keyword argument

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I am running tests on UserDetail view written using Django Rest framework.

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^api/users/', include('calorie_counter.users.urls', namespace='users')),
```

**users/urls.py**

```
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.UserDetail.as_view(), name='user-detail'),
```

**test_api.py**

```
BaseAPITestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.superuser = User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@test.com', 'johnpassword')
        self.client.login(username='john', password='johnpassword')
        self.user1 = User.objects.create(username="user1", password="pass", email="user1@test.com")


class ReadUserTest(BaseAPITestCase):
# check read permissions
    def test_user_can_read_self_detail(self):
        url = '/api/users/'+str(self.user1.id)
        factory = APIRequestFactory()
        request = factory.get(url)
        force_authenticate(request, self.user1)
        response = (UserDetail.as_view())(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

However, running this test, gives me following error. The 'pk' agrument is not getting passed to the UserDetail view.

`AssertionError: Expected view UserDetail to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the .lookup_field attribute on the view correctly.`

How do I test views with URL arguments?

UPDATE:

Now using APIClient instead of factory..

```
def test_user_can_read_self_detail(self):
    client = APIClient()
    client.login(username='user1', password='pass')

    # response = self.client.get('/api/users/', {'pk': self.user.id})
    response = client.get('/api/users/' + str(self.user1.id))
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Now I am getting following error:

```
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'is_manager'
```

where is manager is an attribute of my custom user model. I guess there is some problem with client authentication. I have session authentication enabled. Still getting this error.

UPDATE: My login wasn't working for APICLient because I was creating user using `User.objects.create` instead of `User.objects.create_user`. Changing that fixed the problem. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need all of this set up you're doing, it's unusual to need to instantiate view classes yourself – perhaps you'll have more success leveraging the test client with something like:

```
def test_user_can_read_self_detail(self):
    url = reverse('api:user-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.user.id})
    response = self.client.get(url)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

---

If you're having issues with authentication, which I suspect may have been what lead you here, you may want to try:

```
self.client.login(username='example', password='changeme')
```

or

```
import base64
self.client.defaults['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode('example:changeme')
```

I've used both in the past to test authenticated API endpoints.

Comment: I am getting error in reverse(). I am using reverse('users:user-detail'). I get error: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Comment: I fixed that part by appending user_id to URL. Now I am getting authentication errors,` AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'is_manager'` even after using client and authentication credentials, my test has session authentication enabled.

Comment: I don't think I have enough info to diagnose – but with regards to what you said about auth – remember that DRF's authentication system is entirely independent of Django's – and whilst a Django frontend may be authenticated with session auth, you almost certainly want to be using basic/token/oauth on the API, and may not be authenticating the right way for DRF – I test using the latter auth header to remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Oh my bad – the reverse in my example I lifted from a `POST` request – I have updated it – **tl;dr** you want to pass the `GET` params in to the `kwargs` kwarg to `reverse` not as the second argument to `.get` (the second argument in `.post` is for the request body data)

Comment: @Ajax all sorted? Accept this answer if so :-)

Comment: Accepting your answer because it gives a better solution to the problem. :)